Getting error 403 when going to udemy.com with c#
I am trying to get the details of my subscribed courses with the link subscribed courses (/api-2.0/users/me/subscribed-courses) using the Udemy API despite this call is not specified on the details, but when calling this on the browser it works great, however when calling the information from code I get error 403 Forbidden.
When calling for the information of a course, this works on code, and on browser.
Apparently i believe it is because of the clouflare protection.
I have the following code, where I was trying to get the accessToken to do the call after making a successful login, but i still get error 403.
{
  "udemy": {
    "Username": "user_email@domain.com",
    "Password": "user_password",
    "Client Id": "user_client_id",
    "Client Secret": "user_client_secret",
    "LoginPage": "www.udemy.com/join/login-popup/",
    "APICoursesSubscribed": "www.udemy.com/api-2.0/users/me/subscribed-courses/",
    "APICourseDetail": "www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses/{courseId}"
  }
}

using CloudProxySharp;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using PuppeteerSharp;
using Udemy.API;

using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

class Program
{
    private static APICalls  aPICalls = new APICalls();
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Get course details by ID
        int courseId = 120042;
        var courseDetails = await aPICalls.GetCourseAsync(courseId);
        Console.WriteLine(courseDetails.ToString());

        var subscribedCourses = await aPICalls.GetSubscribedCoursesAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(subscribedCourses.ToString());

        Puppeteer();
        await Selenium();


    }

    private static async Task Selenium()
    {
        var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();chromeOptions.AddArgument(
            "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36");
        //chromeOptions.AddArgument("--remote-debugging-port=9222");
        chromeOptions.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation");
        chromeOptions.AddAdditionalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        js.ExecuteScript("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', { get: () => false });");
        js.ExecuteScript("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'languages', { get: () => ['en-US', 'en'] });");
        js.ExecuteScript("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'plugins', { get: () => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] });");

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(aPICalls.loginPage);
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int delay = rnd.Next(2000, 5000); // Random delay between 2-5 seconds
        Thread.Sleep(delay);

        ReadOnlyCollection<string> windowHandles = driver.WindowHandles;
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(windowHandles[0]);

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
        string element = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            element = "Cookies";
            IWebElement cookies = wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(By.Id("onetrust-accept-btn-handler")));
            cookies.Click();
            element = "Email";
            IWebElement email = wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(By.Name("email")));
            email.SendKeys(aPICalls.username);
            element = "Password";
            IWebElement password = wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(By.Name("password")));
            password.SendKeys(aPICalls.password);
            element = "Submit";
            IWebElement submitButton = wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@type='submit' and contains(@class, 'helpers--auth-submit-button--W3Tqk') and span[text()='Log in']]")));
            submitButton.Click();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Element {element} not found.\n" + ex.Message);
        }

        driver.Quit();
    }

    private static async void Puppeteer()
    {
        var ss = await GetAccessTokenVia_Puppeteer();
        //not working for udemy
         var content = CloudProxySharpCFBypass("www.udemy.com").Result;
        CheckingHeadLessChrome().Wait();
    }

    private static async Task<string> GetAccessTokenVia_Puppeteer()
    {
        try
        {
            var options = new LaunchOptions
            {
                Headless = true,
                ExecutablePath = "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
            };

            using (var browser = await PuppeteerSharp.Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(options))
            using (var page = await browser.NewPageAsync())
            {
                await page.GoToAsync(aPICalls.loginPage);

                // Wait for Cloudflare challenge to complete
                await Task.Delay(10000);
                await page.WaitForSelectorAsync("input[name=email]", new WaitForSelectorOptions { Visible = true });
                await page.WaitForSelectorAsync("input[name=password]", new WaitForSelectorOptions { Visible = true });

                await page.TypeAsync("input[name=email]", aPICalls.username);
                await page.TypeAsync("input[name=password]", aPICalls.password);
                // Submit
                await page.ClickAsync("button[type=submit]");
                await Task.Delay(5000);

                var cookies = await page.GetCookiesAsync();
                foreach (var cookie in cookies)
                {
                    if (cookie.Name == "access_token")
                    {
                        return cookie.Value;
                    }
                }

                throw new Exception("Access token not found.");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            throw new Exception("Access token not found.");
        }
    }

    public static Task<string> CloudProxySharpCFBypass(string url)
    {
        var handler = new ClearanceHandler("http://localhost:8191/")
        {
            //Make sure that the string literal is in single line else it won't work 
            UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
            MaxTimeout = 60000
        };

        var client = new HttpClient(handler);
        var content = client.GetStringAsync(url);
        return content;
    }
    // Just to see PuppeteerSharp in action in an headless chrome settings 
    public static async Task CheckingHeadLessChrome()
    {
        string outputFile = "Shot.png";
        var browserFetcher = new BrowserFetcher();
        await browserFetcher.DownloadAsync();
        var options = new LaunchOptions()
        {
            ExecutablePath = @"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe",
            Headless = false,
            SlowMo = 10
        };
        await using var browser = await PuppeteerSharp.Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(options);
        await using var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
        await page.GoToAsync("www.udemy.com");
        
        var allContent = await page.GetContentAsync();
        var cookies = page.GetCookiesAsync();
        await page.GoToAsync("www.udemy.com");
    }
}

using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Udemy.API
{
    class APICalls
    {
        string credentialsFilePath = "res\\udemyCredentials.json";
        public string clientId;
        public string clientSecret;
        public string APICoursesSubscribed;
        public string APICourseDetail;
        public string username;
        public string password;
        public string loginPage;
        public string accessToken;

        public APICalls()
        {
            // Read and parse the JSON file
            var credentials = ReadCredentials(credentialsFilePath);

            this.clientId = credentials["Client Id"].ToString();
            this.clientSecret = credentials["Client Secret"].ToString();
            this.APICoursesSubscribed = credentials["APICoursesSubscribed"].ToString();
            this.APICourseDetail = credentials["APICourseDetail"].ToString();
            this.username = credentials["Username"].ToString();
            this.password = credentials["Password"].ToString();
            this.loginPage = credentials["LoginPage"].ToString();

            // Log in to Udemy and get the access token
            this.accessToken = GetAccessTokenViaLogin().Result;
        }

        static JObject ReadCredentials(string filePath)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                JObject credentials = JObject.Parse(json);
                return (JObject)credentials["udemy"];
            }
        }


        private async Task<string> GetAccessTokenViaLogin()
        {
            using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler { UseCookies = true })
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                // Step 1: Get the CSRF token from the login page
                HttpResponseMessage getLoginPageResponse = await client.GetAsync("https://www.udemy.com/join/login-popup/");
                string loginPageContent = await getLoginPageResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                // Extract the CSRF token from the login page content
                var csrfToken = ExtractCsrfToken(loginPageContent);
                if (csrfToken == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("CSRF token not found.");
                    return null;
                }

                var requestBody = new MultipartFormDataContent
                {
                    { new StringContent(username), "email" },
                    { new StringContent(password), "password" },
                    { new StringContent(csrfToken), "csrfmiddlewaretoken" }
                };

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Origin", "https://www.udemy.com");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Referer", aPICalls.loginPage+"/?locale=en_US&response_type=html&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.udemy.com%2Flogout%2F");

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(aPICalls.loginPage+"/?locale=en_US&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.udemy.com%2Flogout%2F&response_type=html&response_type=json", requestBody);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    // Print the response for debugging purposes
                    Console.WriteLine(content);

                    // Attempt to extract the access token from cookies if available
                    foreach (Cookie cookie in handler.CookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("https://www.udemy.com")))
                    {
                        if (cookie.Name == "access_token")
                        {
                            return cookie.Value;
                        }
                    }

                    // If the token is not in the cookies, check the response body
                    JObject jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(content);
                    if (jsonResponse.ContainsKey("access_token"))
                    {
                        return jsonResponse["access_token"].ToString();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error obtaining access token: {response.StatusCode}");
                }

                return null;
            }
        }

        private string ExtractCsrfToken(string htmlContent)
        {
            // This is a simple example, you might need to adjust it to match the actual HTML structure
            var csrfTokenStart = htmlContent.IndexOf("csrfmiddlewaretoken") + 22;
            var csrfTokenEnd = htmlContent.IndexOf("\"", csrfTokenStart);
            if (csrfTokenStart > -1 && csrfTokenEnd > -1)
            {
                return htmlContent.Substring(csrfTokenStart, csrfTokenEnd - csrfTokenStart);
            }
            return null;
        }

        public async Task<JObject> GetSubscribedCoursesAsync()
        {
            return await GetPage(APICoursesSubscribed);
        }
        
        public async Task<JObject> GetCourseAsync(int courseId)
        {
            string url = APICourseDetail.Replace("{courseId}", courseId.ToString());

            return await GetPage(url);
        }
        public async Task<JObject> GetPage(string url)
        {
            string encodedClientId = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clientId));
            string encodedClientSecret = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clientSecret));
            string authHeader = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{clientId}:{clientSecret}"));

            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => true;

            using (HttpClient customClient = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                customClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                customClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                customClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Udemy-Client-Id", encodedClientId);
                customClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Udemy-Client-Secret", encodedClientSecret);
                customClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authHeader);

                HttpResponseMessage response = await customClient.GetAsync(url);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return JObject.Parse(result);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {response.StatusCode} ({(int)response.StatusCode})");

                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I tried using Selenium, but upon filling the email and password field i would get an unkown error on udemy login page, and on the console shows severar 403 errors.
I tried using Puppeteer-Sharp, and CloudProxySharp as described here, but no luck either
